# Can you play a spell on your opponent's turn?

Tags: card-wars

In Adventure Time's Card Wars game (the physical card game, not the computer game), can I play a 0 action spell on my opponent's turn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## No, this is explicitly forbidden in rules

According to section "Playing cards → Rainbow cards" of the [rule book](https://cryptozoic.com/sites/default/files/icme/u2082/at_card_wars_rulebook3_0.pdf) (page 5):

> Creatures, Buildings, and Spells with an Action cost of 0 are always Rainbow cards. **They may only be played during your own turn** (even after spending your 2 Actions), but require no Landscape types to play.

[image]

[Source](https://www.cryptozoic.com/games/adventure-time-card-wars-collectors-pack)

Answer (score 1):

The [rulebook](http://cryptozoic.com/sites/default/files/icme/u2082/at_card_wars_rulebook3_0.pdf) seems to suggest that you can only play cards on your own turn, regardless of cost. This isn't explicitly laid out, though it can be inferred from the game giving you actions on your turn only. You could ask on [the forums](http://forums.cryptozoic.com/forumdisplay.php?f=74) though, Cryptozoic employees answer questions there.